# Adaptive menu isn`t hidden when its necessary

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

If the screen or device width is less then `900px` I put a button that opens the menu. (exactly js put `display:inline;` instead of `display:none;`. So I get a problem when I make a width more `900px` (using dev tools google chrome) while the adaptive menu is open - so I have 2 menu bars. Maybe you can offer better ways to create such a menu on small screens.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let headerid = document.getElementById("header-menu");
  let menuStyle = getComputedStyle(headerid);
  document.getElementById("menu").onclick = function() {
    if (menuStyle.display == "none") {
      headerid.style.display = "inline";
    } else {
      headerid.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* header style */

.main-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  min-width: 350px;
}

.header-container {
  margin: 0 2vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.header-menu-display {
  display: none;
}

.text-menu {
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.name {
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.name:hover {
  cursor: default;
}

.underline {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  height: 2px;
}

.pages {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.text {
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 27px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.text:hover {
  color: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header-social-media {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-social-icon {
  width: 30px;
}

.social-media-cont:hover {
  color: gray;
}

.header-social-icon:hover {
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cards-container {
  margin: 0 3vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.card {
  background-color: rgba(223, 223, 223, 0.555);
  height: 500px;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 40%;
  height: 7%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.photo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.country,
.place-name {
  padding-left: 5%;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

p.desc {
  padding-left: 5%;
  height: 76px;
  width: 350px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}


/* Form style */

.form {
  display: none;
  margin: 0 5vw;
}

.form-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.form-input {
  width: 70%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.form-part {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.but {
  width: 110px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.but:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(161, 160, 160, 0.788), rgba(231, 230, 230, 0.774))
}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 1300px) {
  .text {
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: 23px;
    align-self: center;
  }
  .card {
    width: 300px;
  }
  p.desc {
    width: 250px;
  }
  .country,
  .place-name {
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
  }
  .header-menu-display {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 900px) {
  .header-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  }
  .social-media-cont {
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
  .cards-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
  .card {
    width: 90%;
  }
  .pages,
  .header-social-media {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu-bar {
    display: block;
    grid-column: 3;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 700px) {
  .cards-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .card {
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: 10%;
  }
  p.desc {
    width: 350px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 700px) {
  p.desc {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Travel App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3f7264f061.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main-container">
    <hr class="underline">
    <header class="header-container">
      <div class="header-menu">
        <div class="name">Travel </div>
        <div class="header-menu-display" id="header-menu">
          <p class="text-menu">Travel cards</p>
          <p class="text-menu">Add your card</p>
          <div class="social-media-cont">
            <i class="header-social-icon fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
            <i class="header-social-icon fab fa-pinterest"></i>
            <i class="header-social-icon fab fa-twitter"></i>
            <i class="header-social-icon fab fa-instagram"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pages">
        <p class="text">Travel cards</p>
        <p class="text">Add your card</p>
      </div>
      <div class="header-social-media">
        <div class="social-media-cont">
          <i class="header-social-icon fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
          <i class="header-social-icon fab fa-pinterest"></i>
          <i class="header-social-icon fab fa-twitter"></i>
          <i class="header-social-icon fab fa-instagram"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-bar">
        <i class="menu-bar fas fa-bars" id="menu"></i>
      </div>
    </header>
    <hr class="underline">

    <section class="cards-container">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="img/egypt.jpg" alt="" class="photo">
        <p class="country">
          Country: Egypt
        </p>
        <p class="place-name">
          Name: Piramids
        </p>
        <p class="desc">
          Description: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim harum sapiente itaque inventore suscipit praesentium est cupiditate non vel pariatur!
        </p>
        <input class="btn" type="button" value="Show More">
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <img src="img/miami.jpg" alt="" class="photo">
        <p class="country">
          Country: USA
        </p>
        <p class="place-name">
          Name: Miami Bitch
        </p>
        <p class="desc">
          Description: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae quos, eligendi natus voluptate dolorum nam aliquam ad est numquam magni.
        </p>
        <input class="btn" type="button" value="Show More">
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <img src="img/tower.jpg" alt="" class="photo">
        <p class="country">
          Country: France
        </p>
        <p class="place-name">
          Name: Effel Tower
        </p>
        <p class="desc">
          Description: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid eum dolores harum numquam velit sunt tenetur nesciunt, est quia possimus. Quod neque excepturi optio hic explicabo porro exercitationem tempora laudantium similique, magnam
          quos suscipit earum eos, nulla nesciunt debitis itaque modi eius libero molestias repudiandae praesentium? Quos eligendi itaque totam.
        </p>
        <input class="btn" type="button" value="Show More">
      </div>
    </section>

    <form class="form">
      <h2>Add your place</h2>
      <div class="form-container">
        <label for="counrty" class="form-part">Country</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-input" name="country" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter place country">
      </div>
      <div class="form-container">
        <label for="img" class="form-part">Image URL</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-input" name="img" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter image URL">
      </div>
      <div class="form-container">
        <label for="decs" class="form-part">Description</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-input" name="desc" maxlength="100" placeholder="Wright your impression">
      </div>
      <input type="submit" class="but" value="Submit">
    </form>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent such a thing instead of using `window.onload` try to **add an event listener for your window resize** (so whenever window size get resized it will run your script) just like this:

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
  let headerid = document.getElementById("header-menu");
  let menuStyle = getComputedStyle(headerid);
  document.getElementById("menu").onclick = function () {
    if (menuStyle.display == "none") {
      headerid.style.display = "inline";
    } else {
      headerid.style.display = "none";
    }
  };
});
```